# trying to use y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred) but it says Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, inverse-transform

#Dataset

```
Position          Level Salary  
Business Analyst    1   45000   
Junior Consultant   2   50000   
Senior Consultant   3   60000   
Manager             4   80000   
Country Manager     5   110000  
Region Manager      6   150000  
Partner             7   200000  
Senior Partner      8   300000  
C-level             9   500000  
CEO                 10  1000000
```

## SVR

## Importing the libraries

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

## Importing the dataset

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

    # Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler(a
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = np.squeeze(sc_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1)))
```

## Fitting SVR to the dataset

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
```

right here i'm getting error from       y_pre = y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
y_pred = regressor.predict([[6.5]])
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

```
# Visualising the SVR results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Visualising the SVR results (for higher resolution and smoother curve)

```
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.01) # choice of 0.01 instead of 0.1 step because the data is feature scaled
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid, regressor.predict(X_grid), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()






---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-136822b4df3c> in <module>()
      1 y_pred = regressor.predict([[6.5]])
----> 2 y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    771                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    772                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 773                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array)
    774                 )
    775 

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.01150915].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please provide a small snippet of sample data to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: though, your issue is not reproducible, but from the error, it shows you need to do exactly what the error says. If you have one one feature do: `y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred.reshape(-1, 1))` but if you have only one sample then: `y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred.reshape(1, -1))`

Comment: what is the shape of the data that you fit your modal on? and the shape of the data for which you want predictions for? make sure the last dimension of both train and test are the same